# Variables not matching in if/else statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am creating a method that makes you solve random math problems. Code is below:

```
def subtraction()
   puts "Your goal is to solve the math problem."
   # Asks if user is ready
   ready()

   a = rand(0..5)
   b = rand(0..5)
   c = a - b
   puts "what is #{a} - #{b}?"



   prompt; next_move = gets.chomp


     if next_move == c
       puts "Lucky guess!"
       water()       
    elsif next_move != c
      puts "The answer was: #{c}"
      dead("You suck at life")
    else 
      dead("You didn't type anything")
    end
end
```

I keep trying to run this and I keep getting the `elsif` option. Even though my variables match when I check with puts statements. I am not moving in the direction I want to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, it just keeps going to the els if statement. No moving on to the water() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 next_move = gets.chomp
```

to

```
next_move = gets.chomp.to_i # gets.to_i will work also.
```

[`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) will give you string, and you need to convert it to appropriate object as per your need, if your work is not with string object like this example. As  per the line `c = a - b`, I am very much sure, you need to change your `string` object, that you are getting from `stdin` to an integer object. So you have to use [`String#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i).

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Did it work because when I request gets.chomp it makes it an automatic string? Does #to_i make the input seen as an integer?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You kick ass. I understand that Kernal#gets returns a string object.

Comment: @XchelHernandez, if the anwser satisfies you you might want to check it as right

Comment: Sorry - super new and wasn't sure what to do. Thanks for the advice.